# How to access to my model images?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to add the possibility for the user to add many images to his model. But I'm having a hard time trying to access to them. This is my code :

```
class Aircraft(models.Model):
    """ A vehicle capable of atmospheric flight due to interaction with the air, such as buoyancy or lift. """
    name = models.CharField('Nom', max_length=stgs.MAX_CHAR_SIZE, blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.CharField('Possesseur', max_length=stgs.MAX_CHAR_SIZE, blank=True, null=True)
    build_year = models.SmallIntegerField('Année de construction', blank=True, null=True)  # The year
    # when the aircraft was built
    country = models.CharField('Pays', max_length=stgs.MAX_CHAR_SIZE, blank=True, null=True)  # The aircraft country
    manufacturer = models.CharField('Constructeur', max_length=stgs.MAX_CHAR_SIZE, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Date de création', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    edited = models.DateTimeField('Dernière modification', auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def to_dict(self):
        """ Return the aircraft at a dictionary. Useful for export it. """
        raise NotImplementedError('Subclasses must implement this.')


class AircraftImage(models.Model):
    """ Images for each aircraft """
    model = models.ForeignKey('Aircraft', related_name='image')
    image = models.ImageField('Image', upload_to='aircraft/picture/', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "image"
        verbose_name_plural = "images"


class Aerodyne(Aircraft):
    """ A heavier-than-air craft, deriving its lift from motion. """
    matriculation = models.CharField('Immatriculation', max_length=6, unique=True, blank=False, null=True)
    type = models.CharField("Type d'appareil", max_length=stgs.MAX_CHAR_SIZE, blank=True, null=True)
    colors = models.CharField('Couleurs', max_length=stgs.MAX_CHAR_SIZE, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def to_dict(self):
        """ Return the aerodyne at a dictionary. """
        raise NotImplementedError('Subclasses must implement this.')


class Airplane(Aerodyne):
    """ A powered aerodyne with fixed wings. """
    engine = models.CharField('Modèle du moteur', max_length=stgs.MAX_CHAR_SIZE, blank=True, null=True)
    engine_horsepower = models.SmallIntegerField('Puissance du moteur', blank=True, null=True)
    max_range = models.IntegerField("Rayon d'action maximal", blank=True, null=True)
    cruise_speed = models.FloatField('Vitesse de croisière', blank=True, null=True)
    useful_load = models.SmallIntegerField('Charge utile', blank=True, null=True)
    max_passengers = models.SmallIntegerField('Nombre de passagers (pilote[s] compris)', blank=True, null=True)

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'Colors': self.colors,
            'Country': self.country,
            'Cruise speed': self.cruise_speed,
            'Build year': self.build_year,
            'Engine': self.engine,
            'Engine horsepower': self.engine_horsepower,
            'Name': self.name,
            'Manufacturer': self.manufacturer,
            'Matriculation': self.matriculation,
            'Maximum passengers': self.max_passengers,
            'Maximum range': self.max_range,
            'Owner': self.owner,
            'Type': self.type,
            'Useful load': self.useful_load,
        }
```

My question is how to access to this images for show them, delete them trough the children classes ?

EDIT : I put all the models for helping you to understand.

Comment: Can you add some more context to this? Add how, delete how?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some documentation that might help:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

But there are two ways you can get all the Aircraft images of a certain airplane.
Assume the pk of the Airplane model was 1

1:

```
AircraftImage.objects.filter(model__pk=1)
```

2.

```
a = Aircraft.objects.get(pk=1)
a.image_set.all()
```

Comment: I put all my models in my question. With your ways I don't understand how to add, for exemple, a plane with images... Can my `AircraftImage` have a `ForeignKey` to `Aircraft` even if it's an abstract model ?